# Twitter login with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, twitter, webdriverwait

I can't click the *Sign in with Google* button on the twitter login page "twitter.com/login"

Code trials:

```
def tweet(self):
    self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    time.sleep(10)
    login_with_google = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/span[1]')
    login_with_google.click()
```

Pycharm keeps giving me the error:

[image: pycharm error]

What I fail to understand is that I cannot select any element after opening the page even changing selector from `XPATH` to `CSS` or `CLASS`, this hasn't happened to me till now with any other website. Is there something I'm not understanding of the twitter web page?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors or other text; see [ask]

Comment: Sorry for the image, I didn’t know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>Sign in with Google</kbd> element within [***Twitter Login Page***](https://twitter.com/i/flow/login) is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button')]")))
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign in with Google' and not(@id)]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: twitter_signin_google]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the issue:** The desired element is wrapped within an `IFRAME`, in such cases you need to switch into the `iframe` and then perform any actions:

[image]

**Change your code as below:**

```
def tweet(self):
    self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self, 30)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))
    login_with_google = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()='Sign in with Google'][1]')
    login_with_google.click()
```

**Switching back to default content:** To come out of iframe use the code below.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Note:** I changed the XPath expression from your code and modified it to be more user readable, see below:

```
//span[text()='Sign in with Google'][1]
```